# read extjs json with jquery

Tags: jquery, json, extjs, extjs4

i have search but i find almost one answer:
i have a JSON data from extjs source and this format is like this:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonReader

```
    {
    results: 2000, // Reader's configured totalProperty
    rows: [        // Reader's configured root
        // record data objects:
        { id: 1, firstname: 'Bill', occupation: 'Gardener' },
        { id: 2, firstname: 'Ben' , occupation: 'Horticulturalist' },
        ...
    ]
}
```

i requiere read this data from jquery

```
var data = {
results: 2000, // Reader's configured totalProperty
rows: [        // Reader's configured root
    // record data objects:
    { id: 1, firstname: 'Bill', occupation: 'Gardener' },
        { id: 2, firstname: 'Ben' , occupation: 'Horticulturalist' }
    ]
}

for(var i in data){

    $('#datatable').append('<tr><td> '+ i +' </td> <td> '+data[1][i]+' </td></tr>');       
 }
```

but the console show errors

```
TypeError: data[0] is undefined
```

also i have tried with jquery grid plugis but this shows a json format error

Comment: wouldn't it be `data.rows[1]["id"]` for instance?

Comment: Yes, thats run!, thank you